# How to launch program from Perl as a separate process?

Tags: perl, process, sip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fire and forget a process in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl)

I'm looking for a way to invoke a new process from a Perl script, that will let a launched program and a Perl script, from which it's launched, proceed to work concurrently.

The program is [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/), if it's important.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711520/how-can-i-run-perl-system-commands-in-the-background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053093/how-can-i-make-fork-in-perl-in-different-scripts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157848/how-to-spawn-other-programs-within-perl-script-and-immediately-continue-perl-programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want separate processes, then another option is [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html).

```
if (fork) {
  # In the parent program
  # Continue as usual
  ...
} else {
  # In the new child program
  # Replace with another program
  exec $some_other_program;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SIPp has "-bg" commandline parameter.

This parameter launches SIPp in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Proc::Background](https://metacpan.org/module/Proc%3a%3aBackground)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows system you may use "start" command.

For example:

start notepad

OR

start /d"C\Program Files\Sipp3.1" sipp.exe -sn uac