# How can i make a non blocking systems call in perl

Tags: windows, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fire and forget a process in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl)

How can i make a non blocking systems call in perl

I want to do it on windows .

```
system($cmd)
```

I am trying to run this system command

```
system($cmd) ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711520/how-can-i-run-perl-system-commands-in-the-background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053093/how-can-i-make-fork-in-perl-in-different-scripts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157848/how-to-spawn-other-programs-within-perl-script-and-immediately-continue-perl-pro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240483/how-to-launch-program-from-perl-as-a-separate-process

Answer (score 2):

In Windows only, you can use

```
system 1, $cmd;
```

to create and run a detached process.

Answer (score -1):

You can use exec in a child process after you fork:

```
exec( $cmd ) if !fork();
```